# Child form component use multiple times affect each other in Angular

Tags: angular, forms, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms

I'm struggling with a child component used for multiple questions with star ratings. When clicking on a rating star for the 2nd question, it affects the rating display of the 1st question...

Here is how it looks :
[image]

---

**My question :**

How can I display for each question the right star rating when selecting a star / radio button, without impacting the previous question / input ?

---

**Here is the code concerned :**

- Parent component form.ts :

```
export function defaultForm(): EvaluationPageFormGroup {
  return new FormGroup({
    animation: new FormGroup({
      rate: new FormControl<number | null>(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.max(MAX_STAR_RATE),
      ]),
    }),
    quality: new FormGroup({
      rate: new FormControl<number | null>(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.max(MAX_STAR_RATE),
      ]),
    }),
    interest: new FormGroup({
      rate: new FormControl<number | null>(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.max(MAX_STAR_RATE),
      ]),
    }),
    comment: new FormControl<string | null>(
      null,
      Validators.maxLength(MAX_COMMENT_LENGTH),
    ),
  });
}
```

- Parent component template :

```
<form [formGroup]="vm.form">
  <tt-evaluation-stars
    [subGroup]="vm.form.controls.firstQuestion"
    [maxStarRate]="vm.maxStarRate"
    [questionNumber]="1"
    [questionLabel]='"Question 1"'
    [questionDescription]='"Description"'
  ></tt-evaluation-stars>

  <tt-evaluation-stars
    [subGroup]="vm.form.controls.secondQuestion"
    [maxStarRate]="vm.maxStarRate"
    [questionNumber]="2"
    [questionLabel]='"Question 2"'
    [questionDescription]='"Description"'
  ></tt-evaluation-stars>
</form>
```

- Child component template :

```
<div>
  <h3>
    {{questionNumber}} - {{questionLabel}} <span>*</span>
  </h3>
  <p>{{questionDescription}}</p>
  <div [formGroup]="subGroup">
    <fieldset
      class="starRating radiosfield"
      [ngClass]="{'has-checked': subGroup.controls.rate.value !== null}"
    >
      <ng-container *ngFor="let _ of [].constructor(maxStarRate); index as i">
        <input
          class="radio-input starRating-input u-mask"
          type="radio"
          [formControl]="subGroup.controls.rate"
          [value]="i +1"
          [id]="questionNumber + '-' + i +1"
        />
        <label class="starRating-label radio" [for]="questionNumber + '-' + i +1">
          <svg
            class="starRating-label-button"
          >
            [...]
          </svg>
        </label>
      </ng-container>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

  <div class="starRating-subLabel">
    <p>Pas du tout satisfaisant</p>
    <p>Très satisfaisant</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: I think you should adjust `[formControl]="subGroup.controls.rate"` in that way that you set the `formControl` to each and every different rate. Because this type of error occurs, if two or more inputs have the same `formControl` assigned.

Comment: Can you share a code proposition ? As I'm not sure what to do there... 

Comment: better to create a custom form control - https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/

Answer (score 0):

From the given code, your logic is correct and should work as intended. This issue does not occur because of the form setup or how you connected your child (star) components with the parent (form) component.

However, a potential issue might be related to the `id` of each radio input used for the star ratings in your child components. In your case, it's always necessary to have a unique `id` for each radio input element throughout the page to avoid radio-input interaction issues in HTML.

In your existing code, if `questionNumber` and `i + 1` are the same for two distinct inputs, then their `id` would be the same, which might be the cause of the problem.

To avoid this, you can use a unique identifier with `questionNumber` and `i + 1`. A good candidate for this can be the index of questions. If you are looping over questions in your parent template, you can get the index and pass it to the child component. Then use this index in your child component's `id`. The modified code would be something like below.

Parent component template -

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let question of questions; index as idx">
  <tt-evaluation-stars
    [subGroup]="vm.form.controls[question]"
    [maxStarRate]="vm.maxStarRate"
    [questionNumber]="idx + 1"
    [questionLabel]='"Question ' + (idx + 1)"
    [questionDescription]='"Description"'
    [questionIndex]="idx"
  ></tt-evaluation-stars>
</ng-container>
```

Your child component, which now takes `questionIndex` as an `@Input()` -

```
<fieldset
  class="starRating radiosfield"
  [ngClass]="{'has-checked': subGroup.controls.rate.value !== null}"
>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let _ of [].constructor(maxStarRate); index as i">
    <input
      class="radio-input starRating-input u-mask"
      type="radio"
      [formControl]="subGroup.controls.rate"
      [value]="i +1"
      [id]="'question-' + questionIndex + '-' + questionNumber + '-' + i +1"
    />
    <label class="starRating-label radio" [for]="'question-' + questionIndex + '-' + questionNumber + '-' + i +1">
      <svg
        class="starRating-label-button"
      >
        [...]
      </svg>
    </label>
  </ng-container>
</fieldset>
```

This way, you are ensuring that all of your radio input `id`s are unique across the different questions, and it should avoid the unintended interaction between other question's star ratings.